# Run code if no catch in Try/Catch

Tags: c#

When I use Try/Catch, is there a way just like If/Else to run code if there is no error is detected and no Catch?

```
try
{
    //Code to check
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //Code here if an error
}

//Code that I want to run if it's all OK ?? 

finally
{
    //Code that runs always
}
```

Comment: Why not just add your code at the end of try?

Comment: Because you may want any exceptions thrown by the rest of the code to be caught by outer exception handling, and not this inner try/catch block. In which case the best way to do this (that I know of) is to use a bool.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Add the code at the end of your `try` block. Obviously you will only ever get there if there wasn't an exception before:

```
try {
  // code to check

  // code that you want to run if it's all ok
} catch {
  // error
} finally {
  // cleanup
}
```

You probably should change your catch in a way that you only catch exceptions you expect and not flat-out everything, which may include exceptions thrown in »code that you want to run if it's all ok«.

Comment: I don't think this is a great solution especially for built-in error types. As you said "you only catch exceptions you expect". So if I expect a `FooException` to come from `// code to check` then I only include that code in the `try` block. I don't expect a `FooException` from `// code that you want to run if it's all ok`, but your solution would still incorrectly catch that. This is especially a problem with generic error types. However, your solution would be perfect if all functions had there own unique error types.

Answer (score 19):

If you need it to always execute if your `try` code succeeds, put it at the end of your try block. It will run as long as the previous code in your `try` block runs without an exception.

```
try
{
    // normal code

    // code to run if try stuff succeeds
}
catch (...)
{
    // handler code
}
finally
{
    // finally code
}
```

If you need alternative exception handling for you "succeded" code, you can always nest your try/catches:

```
try
{
    // normal code

    try
    {
        // code to run if try stuff succeeds
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        // catch for the "succeded" code.
    }
}
catch (...)
{
    // handler code
    // exceptions from inner handler don't trigger this
}
finally
{
    // finally code
}
```

If your "succeeded" code has to execute after your finally, use a variable:

```
bool caught = false;
try
{
    // ...
}
catch (...)
{
    caught = true;
}
finally
{
    // ...
}

if(!caught)
{
    // code to run if not caught
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Just place it after the code that may throw an exception.

If an exception is thrown it will not run, if one is not thrown, it will run.

```
try
{
    // Code to check
    // Code that I want to run if it's all OK ??  <-- here
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // Code here if an error
}
finally
{
    // Code that runs always
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would write it like this: If the call to a method ran fine then the success is merely the last thing within the `try`

```
try 
{
    DoSomethingImportant();
    Logger.Log("Success happened!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Logger.LogBadTimes("DoSomethingImportant() failed", ex);
}
finally 
{
    Logger.Log("this always happens");
}
```

Comment: Man, SO has quick fingers. You guys should get over to London and compete

Comment: A million monkeys at a million keyboards with a million StackOverflow accounts are likely to produce the right answer fairly quickly :)

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    // Code that might fail
    // Code that gets execute if nothing failed
}
catch {
    // Code getting execute on failure
}
finally {
    // Always executed
}
```